# Uglifier::Error: Unexpected character '“'

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

When trying to deploy to heroku I get the following error:

```
   rake aborted!
   Uglifier::Error: Unexpected character '“'
```

I have modified the production.rb to include `config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)` instead of `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have used a typographic (or "smart") quote character somewhere in your code as opposed to a normal `"` character. Depending on your font, they might look very similar but are different characters, resulting in the error you have seen there.

To resolve this, you should search all of your code and replace all mentions of the `“` character with `"`.